# Getting wrong number when counting rows in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, count

I have a table called quote in my database with 5 rows. However when I try to count the rows it always returns 1 instead of 5. I am using the code below:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("host","username","password","database"); 

$querya = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM quote";
$resulta = mysqli_query($connection, $querya);
$max = mysqli_num_rows($resulta);
$srow = rand(1,$max);

<br /> There are <?php echo $max ?> number of rows
```

I am counting the id column which is a primary key and therefore never null. I have also tried it by using count(*) but get the same result. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It is because you're doing a count (1 row) instead of counting rows. If you want to use `mysqli_num_rows()` remove the `COUNT()` from your query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the pointer re acceppting answers. I appreciate both!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't pair `mysqli_num_rows` with `count`.  If you want to use `mysqli_num_rows` you'd have to `select *` (which would be slow).  Instead `select count(*) as total`, and use `total`.

Comment: Of course! I totally missed that. I just amended by query to SELECT * FROM quote and it works  perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `COUNT()` in your query give it an alias that you can return:

```
$querya = "SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS `Total` FROM `quote`";
$resulta = mysqli_query($connection, $querya);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulta);
echo $row['Total']; // identifier here is the same as the alias in the query
```